# Possible stack overflow on nested loop on the kernel

Tags: cuda

I was getting launch errors on the following code (it is a pattern reduction), and after some time over it, I noticed that for smaller values than 39 for `q` are ok, but if it goes higher I get launch erros.

In the begin I thougth that it was a excessive number for nested loops, but in the botton end, I notice that lower values of `q` are ok even with additional nested loops.

On the cuda debug mode, no error is reported.

**Question**

- Is it a stack error?
- Assuming the maximum value of `q` is equals to maximum value of
  unsigned short does it still doable?

Made the code simple as possible :

```
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "cuda.h"
#include <helper_functions.h>    // includes cuda.h and cuda_runtime_api.h
#include <helper_cuda.h>         // helper functions for CUDA error check
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void loopTest(int q, int *ops, short* best) {
    int i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p;
    const int off(8);
    int maxSum(0), sum;
    const int qi = (q - blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x);
    if (qi < 0) return;
    // qi, the upper for limit reduces as threadId increases
    for (i = 0; i < qi - off + 0; i++) 
        for (j = i + 1; j < qi - off + 1; j++)
            for (k = j + 1; k < qi - off + 2; k++)
                for (l = k + 1; l < qi - off + 3; l++)
                    for (m = l + 1; m < qi - off + 4; m++)
                        for (n = m + 1; n < qi - off + 5; n++)
                            for (o = n + 1; o < qi - off + 6; o++)
                                for (p = o + 1; p < qi - off + 7; p++)
                                    {
                                        sum = i + j + k + l + m + n + o + p;
                                        if (sum > maxSum) {
                                            best[0] = i;
                                            best[1] = j;
                                            best[2] = k;
                                            best[3] = l;
                                            best[4] = n;
                                            best[5] = m;
                                            best[6] = o;
                                            best[7] = p;
                                            maxSum = sum;
                                        }
                                    }
    ops[0] = maxSum;
    printf("max %d:", maxSum);
}

int main() {
    int *d_ops;
    short *d_best;
    cudaError_t cudaStatus;
    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)(&d_ops), sizeof(int));
    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)(&d_best), sizeof(short) * 8);

    // any q value smaller than 39 is fine, no error, but anything higher there is launch error

    loopTest << <1, 1 >> > (38, d_ops, d_best);

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaStatus = cudaGetLastError();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failure: %s", cudaGetErrorString(cudaStatus));
        return 99;
    }
    cudaStatus = cudaFree(d_ops);
    cudaStatus = cudaFree(d_best);
    cudaStatus = cudaDeviceReset();
    cudaStatus = cudaGetLastError();
    getchar();
    return cudaStatus;
}
```

**Background**

Despite of the high often frequence of inactive threads (since the `q` valeu is `intial_q - threadIdx.x`) it does avoid the data transfer from host. This the best way that I found to sweep across alternative cluster partitions.

**Rules**

- all the elements must bellow to a single cluster (a.k.a hard clustering)
- all the clusters must have at least one element
- the elements position in the vector is fixed

**Example**

(4 partitions, 10 elements, clusters bondaries are show bellow)

alt pat 1: 1-1, 2-2, 3-3, 4-10
*(one element per cluster, except the last one tha has the elements {4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 and 10}*

alt pat 2: 1-1, 2-2, 3-4, 5-10
*(same as above, but the 4th cluster has the elements {3 and 4} and the last has the elements {5, 6, 7, 8, 9 and 10}*

...

alt pat x: 1-1, 2-2, 3-9, 10-10

alt pat x+1: 1-1, 2-3, 4-4, 5-10

alt pat x+2: 1-1, 2-3, 4-5, 6-10

...

alt pat y: 1-7, 8-8, 9-9, 10-10

*the last possible partition has the maximum number of elements in the 1st cluster, thus any other cluster has a single element*

Comment: Your launch error is probably a kernel timeout. (You don't have a " high often frequence of inactive threads "; you are only launching 1 thread.)  If you are on windows, google "cuda wddm timeout" and follow the instructions.  If you are on linux, read [this](http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3029/~/using-cuda-and-x).  Also its entirely possible that if you did a better job of error checking (print out the error string) it might even say something like "kernel timed out and was terminated".  Try this: `fprintf(stderr, "failure: %s", cudaGetErrorString(cudaStatus));`

Comment: @RobertCrovella **you are right about TDR! It fixed it, I was going crazy since the error came from nowhere (no changes in the code, just another computer)**. 
I was using the full error string in the complete code, but it only gave me "unspecified launch failure"

About the "high often frequence of inactive threads" since the loop "cap" get smaller as laneID increase, it is expected at least small differences among threads in the same warp, but it is intrinsic to the clustering pattern
Thanks for the supporting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unspecified launch failure was due to the kernel timeout.
It is due to the long processing cost and the TDR windows option as active.
Setting it to off fixed it.